# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java in java.library.path

Tags: java, tomcat

I develop an app that use opencv lib, The projet work fine in tomcat localhost but when I upload the war file in a remote tomcat I get this bug :/ ,

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1894)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
    at org.opencv.osgi.OpenCVNativeLoader.init(OpenCVNativeLoader.java:17)
    at org.dcm4che3.opencv.StreamSegment.<clinit>(StreamSegment.java:76)
```

Comment: You're missing the native (i.e. O/S dependent) library on the target system.  [This page](https://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) has installation instructions for how to install the library.  This isn't a bug - the target system has not been set up correctly.

Comment: but it work without problems in localhost :/, I have to install opencv on server too ?

Comment: Yes because it is a native library.  You're not packaging the share library or DLL with the code.

Comment: for local i added the libopencv_java.jnilib file in jre and it work, but I don't know where I must put this file in remote server :/ , (for the lib I have : linux-i686, linux-x86_64, macosx-x86_64, win-i686, win-x86_64 version)

Comment: What is the operating system of the remote server?  And are you running a 32 bit or 64 bit JVM?  It looks like you have Linux Intel 32 bit and 64 bit, MacOS/X, and Windows Intel 32 and 64 bit libraries.  You need to do about the same on the target system but pick the correct library.

Comment: the operation system is linux amd64, and running a 64 bit JVM

Comment: You'll need to place the `linux-x86_64` library in about the same place you put it in your local environment.  Alternatively, some Linux distributions may have this as a package.  For example, in Ubuntu, you could just do a `sudo apt install libopencv3.2-java`.  Other Linux versions may have something similar.

Comment: thanks @stdunbar it work :) , but some lib in "java/Extensions" in local doesn't work in remote (I don't have this folder in remote server)